# one minute wide-flung - meaning in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading another great story from Clark Ashton Smith, I would like to clarify the following (for the context, Melchior is an amateur astronomer).

> In especial, Melchior was drawn by **one minute wide-flung** constellation
> south of the Milky Way.

WHat exactly does the **one minute wide-flung** part mean? I guess "minute" here could be used as an adjective but that still does not help me with understanding it precisely. I guess "minute" here is not meant in terms of degrees, as one would be probably too few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His attention was drawn to *one* constellation; the adjectives describe that one constellation. The word "one" is a specifier for "constellation".

The word "minute" means that the constellation is not large, probably referring to its appearance to Melchior rather than to the number of stars it contains.

"Wide-flung" refers to the location of the constellation in the sky, not close to the center or other objects.
The writer continues:
[Google Books "Dark Dimensions of Death"](https://books.google.com/books?id=2YtXDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT155&lpg=PT155&dq=In%20especial,%20Melchior%20was%20drawn%20by%20one%20minute%20wide-flung%20constellation%20south%20of%20the%20Milky%20Way.&source=bl&ots=nmPyjwxYx1&sig=ACfU3U2kiMYt6cqmAGHrk87JbakDT-ByWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig8fPyhp3sAhWQK80KHa0kC2IQ6AEwAHoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=In%20especial%2C%20Melchior%20was%20drawn%20by%20one%20minute%20wide-flung%20constellation%20south%20of%20the%20Milky%20Way.&f=false)
"It gave an impression of cosmic solitude and remoteness..."

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing - constellation or galaxy? I believe it is the former (as it is specifically mentioned in the sentence).

Comment: Right, my mistake. Fixed.